# I get error when I use zip.au3 and console.au3 together in an autoit script

Tags: autoit

I get the following error when I use zip.au3 and console.au3 together.  To simulate this error please create a new script in SciTE script editor and include zip.au3 and console.au3 and then run it (just two include lines are sufficient to simulate).  You will get two pop up messages.

Here are the error messages:

First Popup message:

```
AutoIt Error: 
Line 456 (File "C:\Program Files (z86)|AutoIt3\Include\zip.au3:):
$ZipFile=#ZipSplit[2]
$ZipFile=^Error
Error:  Array variable has incorrect number of subscripts or subscript dimension range exceeded.
```

Second popup message:

```
Line 455 (File "C:\Program Files (z86)|AutoIt3\Include\Console.au3:):
If $_Amount_Startup_COnsole Then If^Error
Error:  Variable used without being declared.
```

(I would like to attach zip.au3 and console.au3.  How can I do it?  They are available for download rom Autoit Forum - Example scripts)

Regards,
Nazir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see, the Problem is that the Zip.au3 starts a function at startup which it should not do.

If you delete the first Lines in Zip.au3 then it should work fine:

```
If UBound($CMDLine) > 1 Then
    If $CMDLine[1] <> "" Then _Zip_VirtualZipOpen()
EndIf
```

So my AutoIt dont gives back any Error Messages anymore. But I'm not sure if the other functions will work now. Try it out.

Teifun2

PS: sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Thanks Teifun2.  This solution works.  I don't know which functions will not work, but the function I am using is working.

Comment: @Nazir No Problem :) (if my answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer) Thank you :)  Im not sure if any function will not work, it could be but it dosent has to :)